# How to escape out a backslash in API Request

Tags: api, acumatica

I'm trying to hit the stock item WSE ("~entity/Default/20.200.001/StockItem/{keyvalue}") but when I have a InventoryCD with a slash in it (eg: "WD-ON/OFF") and I run it, I get the error `Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.`

I tried using `WebUtility.UrlEncode("WD-ON/OFF")` to replace the / with %2f, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Per a long shot on the Aug forums, also tried to use "//" but that also does nothing.

The exact same code with a non-slash item works just fine.

Thoughts?

Comment: how about /StockItem?$filter=InventoryID eq 'WD-ON%2FOFF'

Comment: So, interestingly, that does work. In fact if you add it as filter you don't even have to escape out the slash. The problem is the next thing I need to do is use `/entity/Default/20.200.001/StockItem/{keyfield}/files/{filename}` to upload a file and I don't know how to get that to work if I go the filter route.

Answer (score 0):

You should HTML encode your string
string myEncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(filename);

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I'm not doing anything wrong. Acumatica support has sent this to Engineering, and there will be some future fix. For now, "don't do that" is their answer.